# AFNetworking Image cache does not empty on memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, memory, afnetworking

I have an image heavy application where i download images using the UIImageView+AFNetworking category.

I noticed that my memory footprint would continue to rise as i loaded more and more images. When i eventually got a memory notification it did not release any memory - and thus the application crashed. 
My Understanding of This is that AFNetworking uses a subclass of `NSCache` called `AFImageCache` which should handle memory warnings on it's own. [Link 1](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/331) [Link 2](http://nshipster.com/nscache/)

With some dirty hacks, I manually cleared all the objects from the shared cache, and saw a significant decrease in memory allocations. This never seem to happen without manually doing this call.

[image: Allocation instruments]

I have duplicated this in a simple application which downloads the front page of Imgur and displays it in a simple tableview. Above you can see the allocation profiling done for the applpication.

I have tried to remove anything fancy and the code is messy at some places. It does not include my dirty-hack, so it simply dies at memory warnings. You can see the application [here](https://github.com/niklasdstrom/CacheTest).

You need to setup an application at imgur to use it.

Reading through github issues Mattt seem to indicate that it should be enough and fully self maintaining, as long as you set proper cache policy to the NSURLRequest you pass in. I might be missing something, but I'm not certain what cache policy I would set. It all seem to regard refetching changed images rather than clearing for the sake of memory.

I also think lieven is touching on the same problem in this [issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/109) saying that unless the totalCostLimit is set the cache won't self clean. Although I don't trust using the simulator paired with simulated memory warnings in cases like these, the symptoms are the same.

I appreciate any help debugging this

**Edit**

Profiling update after adding the suggested code from

[image]

Comment: hi @niklasdstrom can u tell have you solved this issue...i am still facing the problem and have not got any solution so far...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFNetworking's image cache uses NSCache, which clears on system-wide memory pressure, but not an individual app's memory warning.

To address this, the [2.x branch of AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m) added this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * __unused notification) {
    [_af_defaultImageCache removeAllObjects];
}];
```

which will clear the cache on a memory warning.

If you're still on [the 1.x branch](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/1.x/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m), this code is not included (**UPDATE:** it has been added in [this commit](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/66a29256ed0724e8c9033ee4847e1f09f800ce42#diff-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e)) which can result in the behavior you see.  You could update to 2.x, or just add this code into your app.

> it should be enough and fully self maintaining, as long as you set proper cache policy to the NSURLRequest you pass in

Note that NSCache and NSURLCache are two very different classes.  NSCache is the one you're looking for in your question. NSURLCache, on the other hand, only caches responses to URL load requests.

UIImageView+AFNetworking uses NSCache to store UIImage objects.  NSURLCache stores NSData objects, and retrieving objects from this cache is typically not performant enough for image-heavy applications that show images in a UITableView or UICollectionView.

Finally, you may want to compare your implementation with one that uses the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) project.  SDWebImage offers disk and memory caching, and gives you much more control over the details than AFNetworking's UIImageView+AFNetworking.

Comment: Now I feel very foolish. I thought I had looked through the changes for 2.x and you are correct, I am indeed using the 1.3.x branch, I will take a look at this as a solution. Thanks for the help. Accepting for now, as it seems reasonable.

Comment: No problem.  Lots of people out there still using 1.x.

Comment: Your solution does seem to work. And I will definitely look into SDWebimage, which I remember using a while back. Although I must say I have not run into any real performance issues other than this caching problem.

Comment: I don't think there's a performance difference - SDWebImage just adds disk caching, more control over stuff like whether to retry previously failed URLs, and some goodies like animated GIF support.

Comment: will you please let me know that how i should get instance _af_defaultImageCache

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking now has this fix committed to its 1.x branch and to its 2.x branch. There is no longer any need to upgrade to AFNetworking 2.x to fix the issue. You do not need to edit UIImageView+AFNetworking.m any longer either.

Here is the commit: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/66a29256ed0724e8c9033ee4847e1f09f800ce42#diff-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

You can see the fixed version of the file here:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/1.x/AFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m